no compilation error and i am able to successfully upload the code to node mcu but no output and led not blinking of r307
      #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
      #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
      #include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>


      #define RX_PIN D5 // Connect this pin to RX pin of the fingerprint sensor
      #define TX_PIN D6 // Connect this pin to TX pin of the fingerprint sensor

      // Replace with your WiFi network credentials
      const char* ssid = "xxx";
      const char* password = "xxxxxx";
      const char *device_token = "56800505be080fb4";

      // Replace with your server URL and endpoint
      const char* serverName = "192.168.x.x";
      const int serverPort = 80;
      const char* uploadEndpoint = "/final/rfidattendance/getdata.php";

      // Replace with your module's serial port settings
      SoftwareSerial sensorSerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN); // Use SoftwareSerial for ESP8266
      // Function to fetch fingerprint and send it to the server
      void fetchFingerprintAndSend() {
        // Collect fingerprint image
        sensorSerial.write(0xEF);
        sensorSerial.write(0x01);
        sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
        sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
        sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
        sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
        sensorSerial.write(0x01);
        sensorSerial.write(0x03);

        // Wait for the response
        while (!sensorSerial.available()) {}
        byte response[10];
        sensorSerial.readBytes(response, 10);

        if (response[0] == 0xEF && response[1] == 0x01 && response[2] == 0x07 && response[3] == 0x07 && response[4] == 0x00 && response[5] == 0x00 && response[6] == 0x00 && response[7] == 0x00 && response[8] == 0x14 && response[9] == 0x00) {
          // Generate character file
          sensorSerial.write(0xEF);
          sensorSerial.write(0x01);
          sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
          sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
          sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
          sensorSerial.write(0xFF);
          sensorSerial.write(0x01);
          sensorSerial.write(0x09);

          // Wait for the response
          while (!sensorSerial.available()) {}
          byte charFileResponse[10];
          sensorSerial.readBytes(charFileResponse, 10);

          if (charFileResponse[0] == 0xEF && charFileResponse[1] == 0x01 && charFileResponse[2] == 0x07 && charFileResponse[3] == 0x07 && charFileResponse[4] == 0x00 && charFileResponse[5] == 0x00 && charFileResponse[6] == 0x00 && charFileResponse[7] == 0x00 && charFileResponse[8] == 0x15 && charFileResponse[9] == 0x00) {
            // Read character file
            byte charFile[512];
            sensorSerial.readBytes(charFile, 512);

            // Connect to WiFi network
            WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
            while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
              delay(1000);
            }

            // Send character file to server
            HTTPClient http;
            WiFiClient client;
          http.begin(client, serverName, serverPort, uploadEndpoint);
          http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
          int httpResponseCode = http.POST(charFile, 512);
          int httpResponseCode1 = http.POST(device_token);
            if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
              Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
              Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
            } else {
              Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
              Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
            }
            http.end();
          }
        }
      }

      void setup() {
        // Initialize serial communication with the sensor
        sensorSerial.begin(9600);

        // Initialize serial communication with the computer
        Serial.begin(115200);
        Serial.println("hello");
        // Connect to WiFi network
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
          delay(1000);
        }
      }

      void loop() {
        // Fetch fingerprint and send it to the server
        fetchFingerprintAndSend();

        // Wait for a moment before the next iteration
        delay(1000);
      }`'

in this code no error is coming , no output is shown on serial monitor and led not blinking of r307 fingerprint sensor, i am making a fingerprint based attendance system in which r307 scans fingerprint and send to node mcu then node mcu sends raw fingerprint data to webserver with help of wifi and then i have php code that stores data in database. please help me with this

Why don't you print out charFileResponse to see what you get? Do some basic debugging.

upload of the Blink example works?

use example given in Arduino ide File > Example > Basics > Blink  and second to change your data Cable
